# Cannot ping wired network devices (other than router) from wifi connected devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a D-link router DSL_2740NRU

I have a network with a large number of devices - preferred IP addresses are
192.168.1.1 (router)
.2 My Book Live (MBL) - cabled
.3 PC - cabled
.4 PC - cabled
.10 MS Surface (wifi)
.9 LG TV (wifi)
.15 PS3 - cabled
.14 Android tablet (wifi)
etc - all are on the same IP subnet

My problem began when I could not detect the MBL with the MacBook.  I can ping the router and any wifi devices just fine.  I cannot ping any wired devices.  The problem was the same when I tested wit the Surface Pro.

I concluded it must be in the router, but I can't figure out what setting needs to be changed (it was not set up by me - and wifi internet browsing works fine so I didn't notice this issue until recently)

Comment: Is there any coincidence on the operating systems of the equipments that are not replying to pings? If everything is in the same network, the router shouldn't be interfering this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called wireless privacy you might want to check.

It is a good thing for a public wifi net, you cannot get access to your nieghbours laptop.

Some routers have this configurable, if not then wireless privacy is probably always enabled.

Comment: I checked that function and it appears to be disabled. I did enable multicast, and now the MacBook can detect the My Book Live external drive. problem solved for now but I think shared networking will still be difficult.